# Android app won't let me insert images from gallery previously taken by the camera

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an app where you can choose an image from your phone gallery and then have it put into an image view. Problem is the app works perfectly when choosing any image except for when it was taken by the phone's camera, at which point the app crashes. I have added the following permissions to the Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

And here's the code itself:

```
 public void selectImage(View view) { //is called when the user presses the button to upload an image
         Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
     }
@Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                 try {
                     bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                     img = bos.toByteArray();
                     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
     }
```

If there's any other part of the code you need, I will gladly send it. If anyone has any idea what the problem might be, please do tell. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an error in the log ? Why do you create an `img` variable but do not use it ?

Comment: If an app crashes you will see a stacktrace with exception that you did not catch in Logcat. Please post the relevant lines.

Comment: `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, bos);` Where did you define and initiate bos? Dangerous coding.

Comment: @vincrichaud @blackapps 
The app works fine in the built in emulator and only crashes on actual phones so unfortunately I don't have error logs. If there is a way to get a crash report from the apk on my phone then I can try to get that.

Regarding the `img` variable it's later used for saving the image to a SQL database

Comment: @blackapps
I followed a tutorial for this as I just started learning to make android apps so I'm not entirely sure about this, but the only mention of bos in the code is as seen in the post. Is there a better way of getting this done?

Comment: Android Studio will also collect logs from your device. So use them.

Comment: `, but the only mention of bos in the code is as seen in the post` Impossible. You must have bis declared and initiatef some where.

Comment: @blackapps
This part of the code is taken from here, hopefully helps with the bos mystery
https://techicaltutorial.blogspot.com/2020/04/upload-image-sqlite-database-android.html